# What was the rationale behind having the receiver in functions default to the global object?

Tags: javascript

In early versions of JavaScript, what was the rationale behind having the `receiver` (aka `context`) default to the global object?

```
function a() {
  console.log(this); // window
}
```

Comment: @Cerbrus: not really, you don't often use `this` inside a function to access globals (and linters will pull you up on it).

Comment: You would have to ask [Brendan Eich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) for his reasons ,-)

Comment: @AndyE: Owwait, I'm being silly, disregard what I just said :P

Comment: May be, it was a mistake :)

Comment: My guess would be that it simplified things if `this` was always a valid object, but I'd be surprised if anyone comes up with a well-sourced answer.

Comment: I like this question, but i think it will end up being opinion based. After my 1hr research i couldn't find any detailed information about the design decisions behind *this*. Hopefully Brendan Eich will show up and give us an answer!

Comment: @TheZenCoder Concur! I'll tweet him.

Comment: Great! Share the tweet here!

Comment: Brendan has been asked: https://twitter.com/benastontweet/status/550245227102212097

Comment: This question is not opinion-based. It is looking for a factual answer. Admittedly, it seems like the only people who might know the answer were the original creators of the language, but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: This is *still* the case, unless you add `'use strict';` to your scripts.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm sorry, I don't understand your point. I am fully aware that 'use strict' changes the behaviour from ECMAScript 5 on. This question is about ECMAScript 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @Ben: I was just commenting in case someone didn't know.  You said "early versions", I just wanted to specify is all.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh, OK fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brendan Eich [answered](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/550346567656275968):

> So that top-level functions (the only kind in first release) can act
> as window or frame (later, iframe) methods. Still used.
>
> JS jargon nit: "receiver" is the standard OO term in languages
> that influenced JS, rather than highly-overloaded "context".

Question posed to Brendan Eich:

> So ES1 did not have methods? (cf ur comment on top level fns)

Brendan Eich:

> No, JS1 in '95 (no "ES" then) had methods via
> function-valued properties, but all functions were top level.
> ES1 standardized.
>
> ES3 in '99 added function expressions & nested functions
> (closures), which I didn't have time to implement in those 10 days.
>
> To go back to orig q: in window w, function m(){} makes w.m()
> callable from other reachable windows/frames with `this` == w.

Comment: Since I'm not used to the first days of JS I don't fully understand this. So I have posted it as community wiki, feel free to improve it.

Comment: One interpretation, I guess, is that a method like `window.addEventListener` is a "window method". They wanted people to be able to write *new* window methods (`window.addSuperTurboEventlistenerTournamentEdition`) that didn't depend on the `window` global object. So, when adding a new top-level function (the only kind they were considering initially), it's treated as a "window method". I guess that kind of makes sense, in the way that JavaScript as a language barely makes sense.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly the choice of defaulting the `receiver` to the global object (i.e. `window`) stemmed from an attempt to make working with multiple windows (and later iframes) more convenient.

Comment: I think that Brendan greatly escaped to answer the question in full detail! the real problem are not top-level functions, because for them it even makes sense to have this associated with the global execution context, but i would like more an explanation why nested functions context should be associated with the global context. THAT is the real question.

Answer (score 1):

So that top-level functions could be trivially invoked as bare functions (i.e. not as methods) from other windows and frames associated with the same "top" window.

For example, if a page contains two frames, each of which defines its own function `foo` that logs a property of the global object. Like so:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <title>index.html</title>
  <frameset cols="30%,70%">
    <frame name="Frame1" src="frame1.html">
    <frame name="Frame2" src="frame2.html">
  </frameset>
```

frame1.html

```
<html>
  <title>frame1.html</title>
  <script>
    function foo() {
      console.log('frame1::foo: ', this.id);
    }
    this.id = 'window object one!';
  </script>
```

frame2.html

```
<html>
  <title>frame2.html</title>
  <script>
    function foo() {
      console.log('frame2::foo: ', this.id);
    }
    this.id = 'window object two!';
  </script>
```

If we now run the following from a index.html:

```
var foo1, foo2;
foo1 = window.top.Frame1.foo;
foo2 = window.top.Frame2.foo;

foo1(); // "window object one!"
foo2(); // "window object two!"
```

So, we can see that the receiver defaults to the global object of the context of the function.

An alternative implementation would have been to have bare functions have the receiver default to undefined, but AFAICT this was perceived as being "less convenient" during the early days of JavaScript. Remember JS was originally developed with non-professional developers in mind.

The question becomes more interesting when we ask, why was this behaviour extended to nested functions and function expressions (standardised in ES3, but implemented beforehand)? My guess based on reading Brendan Eich's responses is that this simply wasn't a recognised problem at the time of the development of nested functions and function expressions, and so the existing behaviour, based on top level functions was used.

The issue was only formally recognised in ES5 with `"use strict"`.